# Legitimate use cases for UpgradeableReadLock

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, thread-safety, locking

I was recently reminded of the UpgradeableReadLock construct C# provides and I'm trying to discern when it really makes sense to use it.

Say, for example, I have a cache of settings that are heavily read by many classes, but periodically need to be updated with a very low frequency based on a set of conditions that aren't necessarily deterministic...

would it make more sense to simply lock like so:

```
List<Setting> cachedSettings = this.GetCachedSettings( sessionId );

lock(cachedSettings)
{
    bool requiresRefresh = cachedSettings.RequiresUpdate();
    if(requiresRefresh)
    {
        // a potentially long operation
        UpdateSettings( cachedSettings, sessionId );
    }

    return cachedSettings;
}
```

or use an UpgradeableReadLock:

```
public class SomeRepitory {

private ReaderWriterLockSlim _rw = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public List<Setting> GetCachedSettings( string sessionId )
{
    _rw.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();

    List<Setting> cachedSettings = this.GetCachedSettings( sessionId );

    bool requiresRefresh = cachedSettings.RequiresUpdate();
    if(requiresRefresh)
    {
        _rw.EnterWriteLock();

        UpdateSettings( cachedSettings, sessionId );

        _rw.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    _rw.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();

    return cachedSettings;
}
```

perhaps what confuses me the most is how we can get away with checking if an update is required outside of the write block. In my example above I am referring to when I check for where a refresh is required, but to simplify I'll use an example from "C# 5.0 In A Nutshell":

```
while (true)
{
    int newNumber = GetRandNum (100); 
    _rw.EnterUpgradeableReadLock(); 
    if (!_items.Contains (newNumber)) 
    {
        _rw.EnterWriteLock();
        _items.Add (newNumber);
        _rw.ExitWriteLock();
        Console.WriteLine ("Thread " + threadID + " added " + newNumber);
    }
    _rw.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
    Thread.Sleep (100);
}
```

my understanding is that this allows concurrent reads unless a thread needs to write, but what if two or more threads end up with the same random number and determine `!_items.Contains(newNumber)`? Given my understanding that this should allow concurrent reads (and correct me if I have misunderstood, of course).. it seems that, as soon as a write lock is obtained, any threads that were concurrently reading would need to be suspended and forced back to the start of `_rw.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();` ?

Answer (score 2):

Of course your second approach is better in case of many simultaneous readers and relatively rare write operations. When read lock is acquired (using `_rw.EnterUpgradeableReadLock()`) by a thread - other threads can also acquire it and read the value simultaneously. When some thread then enters write lock, it waits all reads to complete and then acquires exclusive access to lock object (all other threads trying to execute EnterXXX() operations wait) to update the value. When it releases the lock, other threads can do their job.

First example `lock(cachedSettings)` blocks all other threads so that only one thread can read the value at a time.

I would recommend in addition use the following pattern:

```
_rw.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
try
{
    //Do your job
}
finally
{
    _rw.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
}
```

for all Enter/Exit lock operations. It ensures ([with high probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533104/is-it-completely-safe-to-use-pattern-of-readerwriterlockslim-enterxxx-with-con)) that if exception happened inside your synchronized code, lock won't remain locked forever.

**EDIT:**
Answering Martin's comment. If you don't want multiple threads updating the value simultaneously, you need to change your logic to achieve that. For example, using a [double-checked lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) construct:

```
if(cachedSettings.RequiresUpdate())
{
    _rw.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        if(cachedSettings.RequiresUpdate())
        {
            UpdateSettings( cachedSettings, sessionId );
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _rw.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

This will check if while we were waiting for write lock other thread haven't refreshed that value already. And if value doesn't require refresh anymore - just release the lock.

**IMPORTANT:** it's very bad to take exclusive lock for long time. So it the `UpdateSettings` function is long-running, you better execute it outside the lock and implement some additional logic to allow readers read expired value while some thread is refreshing it. I used to implement cache once and it's really complex to make it fast and thread-safe. You better use one of the existing implementations (for example `System.Runtime.MemoryCache`).

Comment: but what if two threads, for the same session/context, check RequiresUpdate before the write lock is obtained and you end up with two threads that have a requiresRefresh value of true... then won't the UpdateSettings method, a potentially and relatively long running method, end up getting called twice?

Comment: If write lock thread waits for all read locks to complete, the code posted by @Martin will deadlock in following scenario: _items is empty, threads 1 and 2 enter reader lock, thread 1 tries to enter write lock and waits for thread 2 to complete, thread 2 also tries to enter write lock and never completes - Dead Lock. Or am I wrong? Edit: Conclustions lock(chacheSettings) is slow, but bulletproof :)

Comment: @RytisI, very good question! But I've used this pattern a lot and never seen a deadlock in such scenario. I think that's why the EnterUpgradableReadLock() exists separately from EnterReadlock(). Probably when upgradable lock try entering WriteLock(), it releases the lock for writer (if any) in the writers queue. If no writers in the queue - it acquires the write lock. Though I'm not sure in this behavior. Just a guess...

Comment: Yes that's part of my question - how the underlying mechanism works :)

Comment: #Martim, I can't answer it for sure and anyway even if I could - it wouldn't fit into reasonable-size answer. It's closer to a book in size. I read Jeffrey Richter's "CLR via C#" (http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Edition-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454) and that describes it in more or less explainable way. Not not in all details.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy - while your update would work and is appreciated, I'm looking to better understand how this EnterUpgradableReadLock() method works behind the scenes.. let's not focus on optimization and assume that perhaps for some security reason that no threads are able to access the cache at the point where it requires an update

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy also worth noting that I picked up a copy of "CLR via C#" :)